# attachment getting validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an application where users can upload videos and .vtt caption files.

The issue I'm having is that I get the following error messages when attempting to upload a .vtt file:

```
Caption has an extension that does not match its contents
Caption is invalid
Caption content type is invalid
```

Here is my validation for the field, I've included 'text/vtt' format, what is the issue?

```
  validates_attachment_content_type :caption, :content_type => ['application/txt', 'text/plain', 'text/vtt']
```

Comment: Can you put the line before `.save` like `puts attachment_content_type`..? and tell me what it prints

Comment: As Arup said, you need to determine what the file type actually is; it's quite obscure

Comment: Thanks Arup, where do I add puts attachment_content_type? there's no .save in the model